# Hermitian Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, matrix-elements

What is the geometrical significance of the Hermitian matrix? Actually what does the conjugate of the transpose represents. As a determinant if 3 by 3 expresses the volume.

Comment: May be you can find your answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/598258/

Answer (score 2):

In the space of real $N \times N$ matrices, define a matrix $A$ to be symmetric if it satisfies $A^T=A$. i.e., the transpose is itself. You can visualize this pretty easily.

What's the deal with symmetric matrices? Given a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x^T A x$ determines a quadratic form in the entries of $x$. The signature of the quadratic form (loosely, whether it has a minimum, maximum, or a saddle) is determined by the eigenvalues (which exist, and are all real, thanks to the finite dimensional spectral theorem!)

Now extend this to Hermitian matrices (i.e. consider complex matrices too). It's the same concept entirely (the spectral theorem works too!), except the reason we take the CONJUGATE transpose instead of just the transpose is the way the inner product works in complex space:

Given a row vector $x$ and a column vector $y$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$, we define the inner product to be $x\bar{y}$. (sometimes people take x to be conjugated, doesn't matter, everything is isomorphic). Now, when we're taking the transpose, what are we really doing? We are changing row vectors to column vectors, and vice versa. The inner product (read: dot product) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ doesn't care which vector is row vector and which is column vector since we don't need to do any conjugation, but in complex space we do care. Hence, whenever we turn column vectors into row vectors and vice versa, we have to conjugate to preserve the meaning of inner products which determine the geometry of complex space.

Why did I ramble this much? Just to show you that Hermitian matrices are just an extension of symmetric matrices, except we had to do something a little extra to make it work for complex numbers. Symmetric (Hermitian) matrices are very important because we have the spectral theorem for them, i.e. they admit an orthonormal eigenbasis. Just from this alone, we have a way of calculating the nature of a Hermitian operator by looking at its eigenvalues. In a geometric sense, we define quadratic forms with Hermitian operators and see whether or not they look like saddles.

Comment: What if i were to teach a people who don't understand mathematics.

Comment: Well this is some quite high level maths...I tried to help by explaining it in terms of lower level maths. I guess you can explain it as a matrix that defines a quadratic form in the complex numbers...but I don't know, im sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry for that. I was just inquiring you, if i you could make it simpler for me to understand. Anyways thanks for you little words. Thank you very much, sir. If you find any easier do let me know. Thanks, i'll try my best to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some nice analogies between complex numbers and matrices which helped my intuition:
\begin{matrix}
z \in \mathbb{C}   & A \in \textrm{Matrices over } \mathbb{C}                                            \\
\textrm{Real: } z = z^*            & \textrm{Hermitian: } A = A^{\dagger}                                           \\
\textrm{Imaginary: } z = -z^*      & \textrm{Antihermitian: } A = - A^{\dagger}                                     \\
1              & \textrm{Identity } \mathbb{I}                                                 \\
\textrm{Modulus 1: }|z|=z z^* =1 & \textrm{Unitary } U U^{\dagger}=1                                             \\
\textrm{Nonnegative: }z\geq 0      & \textrm{Positive Semidefinite: } \langle \psi | A |\psi \rangle \geq 0 \,\,\,\forall \, |\psi\rangle
\end{matrix}

However these are not just analogies. The definitions for matrices tend to be very similar to the definitions for complex numbers, but they weren't just defined to look similar. It just so happens that these similar-looking definitions give us exactly the properties we need in physics.

I will only go in depth about Hermitian because that was your question.

**Observation 1:** When we do a measurement in a real experiment, only get a real number back. The position is $x=4m$, or the energy is $E=2J$. In quantum mechanics, the possible results from an experiment are the eigenvalues of an operator (or matrix) which we call an "observable". There is$^*$ one observable for every quantity which we can measure in an experiment: $x$, $p$, $H$, $L$, etc.

*Therefore, the eigenvalues of an observable $A$ better be real.*

**Observation 2:** Quantum mechanics speaks in probabilities. The output of the theory is not a single number, but rather a probability assigned to each possible measurement outcome. In order to assign a probability to *every* measurement outcome, the eigenvectors of the measurement operator must span the whole space. In other words, we should be able to write any state $|\psi \rangle$ as a superposition of states which are eigenvectors of $A$.

*Therefore, the eigenvectors of $A$ must span the whole space of states $\{|\psi \rangle \}$*.

It turns out that these two requirements are exactly equivalent to the definition of hermitian above (for matrices. For operators you have to be a bit more careful, but it's the same idea). You could *define* hermitian as a matrix with real eigenvalues, whose eigenvectors span the space of states.